# Creating a TestActorRef results in NullPointerException

Tags: scala, testing, akka, actor

I am trying to get a TestActorRef like that

```
class NotifySenderTest(_system: ActorSystem) extends TestKit(_system) with ImplicitSender with WordSpecLike with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll with BeforeAndAfter {

  def this() = this(ActorSystem("NotifySenderTest"))
  override def afterAll {
    TestKit.shutdownActorSystem(system)
  }

  "A NotifySender" must {
    "be able to process the required messages" in {
      val actorRef = TestActorRef[NotifySender] //Line 92
    }
  }
```

the this actor

```
class NotifySender extends Actor with Stash {
  import Tcp._
  import context.system

  def receive = {
  [...]
  }
}
```

But this leaves me with the following stacktrace

> java.lang.NullPointerException:   at
>   akka.actor.dungeon.Dispatch$class.init(Dispatch.scala:62)   at
>   akka.actor.ActorCell.init(ActorCell.scala:338)   at
>   akka.actor.LocalActorRef.(ActorRef.scala:304)   at
>   akka.testkit.TestActorRef.(TestActorRef.scala:21)   at
>   akka.testkit.TestActorRef$.apply(TestActorRef.scala:141)   at
>   akka.testkit.TestActorRef$.apply(TestActorRef.scala:137)   at
>   akka.testkit.TestActorRef$.apply(TestActorRef.scala:146)   at
>   akka.testkit.TestActorRef$.apply(TestActorRef.scala:144)   at
>   actor.NotifySenderTest$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$4.apply$mcV$sp(NotifySenderTest.scala:92)
>   at
>   actor.NotifySenderTest$$anonfun$2$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$4.apply(NotifySenderTest.scala:91)
>   ...

Edit: It seems to have something to do with this actor in particular. Getting a TestActorRef to another actor class is working correctly. I read that there was a problem with TextActorRefs for actors that have the Stash trait, but this was said to be resolved in the current version. ([Reference](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/akka/tickets/3556))

Edit2: Ok. I was wrong. The current release is not 2.3. So I have to wait?!

Comment: Yes, this issue is fixed in 2.3.0-RC2, but we cannot backport it to 2.2.x due to binary compatibility issues.

Comment: Do you know the release date of version 2.3.0 stable?

Comment: “Knowing” is difficult because it lies in the future, but the current plan is in two weeks, as I’m preparing an RC3 right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Verified that upgrading to [akka 2.3.0](https://typesafe.com/blog/akka-230-major-release) is the correct answer for fixing `TestActorRef` with the `Stash` trait.

Comment: For me to be able to use `Stash` with `TestActorRef`, I also had to change the dispatcher. Without changing the dispatcher, `unstashAll()` would not work. See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34308851/936869)

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate the actor:

```
val actorRef = TestActorRef(new NotifySender())
```

That's how I always go about it anyway. :)

Comment: I already tried this resulting in this stack trace: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8532ca52c6d53b88e6f9

Comment: Yeah, the problem is definitely with `Stash` as you have already pointed out in your edit.  My team uses 2.2.3, but I've not used `Stash` before.  Does it work with that akka version, or are you dependent upon some 2.3 features?

Comment: I'm also using akka 2.2.3 but with this version it is not possible to create a TestActorRef for an actor with the stash trait. Therefore, it is necessary to wait for version 2.3 to come up.